# How to turn a router into CoAP server or MQTT broker

Tags: mqtt, routers, coap

Can we turn a router to a **MQTT broker or CoAP server**? or can we just take **additional service** from the router by installing CoAP or MQTT broker on it, probably in `Java`.
The router can be powerful as **Linksys WRT1200AC** (1.3 GHz Dual Core with 512MB RAM and 128MB flash) or we need some thing extra powerful to make it work.

Kindly suggest. I have no experience flashing a router.

Comment: This question is unanswerable without knowing a lot more information. Also Java on a router is probably not the best fit as it tends to be more resource intensive

Comment: yes it will be resource intensive, I want it for some experimental purpose

Comment: You seam to have ignored the first half of my comment, which is the important bit

Comment: Router *hardware* running custom Embedded Linux builds can indeed be a good platform for this kind of thing, but you wouldn't run Java on it unless you buy hardware that is more powerful than otherwise needed, and probably run a derivative of a "full" Linux distribution rather than a "router" or IoT type of Linux distribution such as OpenWrt.

Comment: I've put your question on hold as unclear to give you chance to respond to the points raised in the comments. Specifically: what exact model of router are you thinking of? That should help to determine whether the router is capable of additional modification such as this. Once you [edit] your post, it will automatically be sent for review, so be sure to update this.

Comment: Can you pick a specific router and possibly one of the protocols? In that case we'd have something to work with.

Comment: @Helmar I can change the router you suggest, incase CoAP will be fine

Comment: @aquestion requests for hardware recommendations are generally off topic in the SE system as a whole